# Why is the Get method missing from MoqMockingKernel?

Tags: c#, ninject, moq

I'm using `MoqMockingKernel` following the [example from the wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.mockingkernel/wiki/Examples) but the `Get()` method is missing. My simplified code:

```
using Moq;
using Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq;

namespace Store.Web.Tests.Controllers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PeopleControllerTests
    {
        private MoqMockingKernel _mockingKernel;        

        [TestInitialize]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _mockingKernel = new MoqMockingKernel();            
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AddAnotherPersonAddsAnotherPerson()
        {
            // There is no Get method on _mockingKernel
            var peopleController = _mockingKernel.Get<PeopleController>();                      
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? It has `GetHashCode()`, `GetMock()`, `GetModules()`, and `GetType()` but no `Get()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally figured it out. `Get()` is an extension method that lives in the `Ninject.ResolutionExtensions` class. Adding `using Ninject;` solved the problem. None of the examples show which namespaces you need to use which is frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for that. .Net code examples is plagued by the "guess which random namespace an extension method is put in".

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, saved me a few minutes :)